# Powershell command to restart app pool in Azure - App service Slot

Tags: powershell, azure

Can any one tell me powershell command to restart app pool in azure App Service Slot.

I can see RestartWebsite command but cannot find any command to restart app pool.

Why this Requirement: I am doing deployment via slot and before swapping I am changing few things in Web.config file using command 
get-content D:\home\site\wwwroot\Web_prod.config | out-file Web.config
 where Web_prod config file contains content which we want to copy in Web.config. When we do this staging gives Internal server error as app pool is not restarted . As soon as I do any change in Web.config it gets restarted this time.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to achieve what you want. The closest thing you can do is kill the w3wp process for the instance. Or restart the whole WebApp.

Comment: This restart the Slot but I need to restart web app pool of slot. Restarting Slot is not restarting web app pool. When I do any change in web.config manually it restart app pool.

Comment: Tried killing w3wp process but was not successful. Can you tell me if this command is adding some extra character because of which app pool is getting hanged :Command      -   get-content D:\home\site\wwwroot\Web_prod.config | out-file Web.config

Comment: it should not, can't you verify using some online diff checker?

Comment: out-file was creating issue. I am using Set-Content instead of out-file now and not facing any issue

Comment: this is weird, glad you sorted it out thou.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved when I replaced out-file in
D:\home\site\wwwroot\Web_prod.config | out-file Web.config 
with Set-Content:
D:\home\site\wwwroot\Web_prod.config | Set-Content Web.config